# Property Get via Lambda Expression

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have gotten quite use to being able to use lambda throughout my c# projects and in Visual Studio 2015 preview I can now use my properties as so:

```
public ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel> Workspaces => workspaces ?? (workspaces = new ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel>());
```

or

```
public string Something => something;
```

However when switching between Visual Studio 2015 and 2013... 2013 doesn't like them :(

Is there a way I can force 2013 to read these expressions and compile them properly, I understand MSbuild is open source now, do I have to tell 2013 to use a new version of MSbuild?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a c# 6 feature, you can get it working in VS 2013 but it seems that is no longer updated and was just used for previews.

[How can I add C# 6.0 to Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462553/how-can-i-add-c-sharp-6-0-to-visual-studio-2013?lq=1)

From the [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) site it says

> You can also try April's End User Preview, which installs on top of
>   Visual Studio 2013. (note: this VS 2013 preview is quite out of date,
>   and is no longer updated)

Who knows if it will come out in VS2013 again...